# Google Chrome frameless (like kiosk)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want know if is it possible to make Google Chrome behave like a kiosk (without a frame or controls) but not in full screen, like the next mock picture:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution in Electron:

```js
var app = require('app');  // Module to control application life.
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');  // Module to create native browser window.

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is GCed.
var mainWindow = null;

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
app.on('ready', function() {
 // Create the browser window.
 mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600, frame:false});

 // and load the index.html of the app.
 mainWindow.loadURL('http://www.google.com/');

 // Emitted when the window is closed.
 mainWindow.on('closed', function() {
   // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
   // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
   // when you should delete the corresponding element.
   mainWindow = null;
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that it's possible to make Chrome itself behave that way, but a [Chrome App](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps) (not an extension) can do this.

This is an [option](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#property-CreateWindowOptions-frame) in window creation:

```
chrome.app.window.create("app.html", {
  frame: "none"
});
```

Note that you will have to provide your own controls to close/move the window.

To make it behave like a browser, you'll need to embed a [`<webview>` element](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview). See also a [browser app example](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/webview-samples/browser).

---

However, note that Chrome Apps [are being deprecated](http://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html).

You should consider using a similar platform, like [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) or [NW.js](http://nwjs.io/), to build your own "mini-browser" for your purpose.

Comment: Ok Xan, thanks for your reply!! I will try to make my own browser with QT and my own controls, I think that it's one possibility.

Comment: Consider not reinventing the wheel and using something like Electron or NW.js - it may be much, much simpler.

Comment: Thank you very much!! with Electron rules!!